# community about installation/configurations of programs

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange community about installation/configurations of programs?
I have configuration questions about OpenText Archive Center.

Comment: Did you searched in the other stackexchange websites ?

Comment: I didn't find a question/answer in StackOverflow. StackOverflow is just a **programming** community. But I need only configuration things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what kind of program you are trying to configure.

If the program is an application that is primerily used by programmers, like vim, eclipse, etc, you can ask on Stack Overflow.

If the program is not related to programming, then it may be on topic on super user, but read their help center before posting.

Comment: Thanks. SuperUser seems to be the right place.